# can't mirror objects on other side

Tags: mirror, scale

i'm trying to mirror 3 still objects that are: shoulder, biceps and forearm.
i remember it was like this: select all of them, center the cursor to world origin (shift + c), duplicate, scale, x, -1. but the rotation screws up for some reason. same for the legs

[image]

Comment: maybe apply the rotation of your object before making the mirror

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it seems counterintuitive, how <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> work in this case.

You can always apply a mirror matrix to the object matrix. Simply select the object and execute the following script.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

ob = bpy.context.object

mat_mirror = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(-1, 4, (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ob.matrix_world = mat_mirror @ ob.matrix_world

# For Blender 2.79 and previous, use the * symbol for matrix multiplication.
#ob.matrix_world = mat_mirror * ob.matrix_world
```

With `mathutils.Matrix.Scale(-1, 4, (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))` we construct a matrix scaled `-1` along X.